# itext 5 TextField using chinese font with bold and italic

Tags: java, itext

I'am trying to using TextField in itext 5.
My font name is "微軟正黑體" in English is "Microsoft JhengHei".
I want to using this font with bold and itatic.

Init Font ( 3 is Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC and BC is my base color)

```
Font fontZh = FontFactory.getFont(CurrentFont.getFontName(), BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED,
                    CurrentFont.getFontSize(), 3, BC);
```

I have a textField variable and set fontZh to setFont.

```
field.setFont(fontZh.getBaseFont());
```

The pdf result only the font style, size and color is correct. But the bold and itatic isn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can only set a `BaseFont` to a field. This in particular means that those properties from your `FontFactory.getFont` call which merely become part of the returned `Font` and not of the underlying `BaseFont`, are not in the base font you retrieve using `fontZh.getBaseFont()` and, therefore, are not set to the field.

Among the properties that get lost this way are in particular style information like *italic* or *bold* (unless the referenced font file already is italic or bold or the referenced font family is registered with a bold or italic font file) and the color.

<sub>(You say that in your test the *color is correct*; if it is, that is not because of it being transported via the font. As you don't show enough code for a good analysis, I can only guess; I would surmise that the color either is the default to start with or you set it using some other instruction.)</sub>

Thus, if you want to have a bold or italic font used in a text field, you should use a base font that references a font file which already draws characters in the desired combination of bold and italic, e.g. in case of *Century Gothic* use `GOTHICBI.TTF` instead of `GOTHIC.TTF`. I don't know whether you have such a variant of "微軟正黑體".

If you want to set the color of the font of a field, you can do so by setting it to the field, i.e.

```
field.setTextColor(BC);
```

before building the field dictionary using `field.getTextField()`.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. I will search my font bold and italic. If I can't find my font bold and italic, is there a way to convert the normal ttf or ttc font file to bold or italic?

Comment: I don't know but I would assume that there is a tool for that. The results may not be perfect but should be acceptable.